# Login with different accounts

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to create my application with Google app maker  and Ineed to create login with different accounts? how can I create a login with different users roles and each user has a specific pages to see

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do this. Please click on the links in my answer below to go to the screenshot I've added for reference.

1. Go to App Settings -> Security and [add roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXF6g.png) you would like to create for your app in the space provided.
2. In a page, you can go to the Property Editor, scroll down to Security and [mention who can see this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTgZ2.png).
3. In a model, you can add controls by going to the Security tab and [selecting relevant roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uv7q.png) for specifying who can create, load, save or delete records for that model.
4. Finally, to mention which email address goes into which role, you can go to a specific deployment and [add the email addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xXN6.png) for each role manually.

Let me know if this helps. Feel free to ask any questions you may have!

Comment: Yeah, thank you. What about doing a login page in app maker for my application is it possible to create registration and login with app maker with different emails or only the user under my domain in G suite can use and access to my app ?

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#gsm), I think it's not possible to allow users outside your domain to access your AppMaker app.